# What will be the impact on any Script if we run >./script.sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Few days back I was executing one script at one particular location and instead of ./x.sh i have given >./script.sh.... will it remove the content of the script and make it empty.

So, when I was running ./x.sh it was not executing ad was not working....I was supposed to start the app with this script but not sure what it does.

Comment: Restore a backup of that file

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your script was truncated and all content inside ./script.sh was removed. Operator explanation:

```
> {Truncates the content of the given file}
>> {Appends information to the file}
```